# Поддержка соединения с вебсокет сервером

Tags: c

В общем, я подключился к вебсокет серверу и мне необходимо через определенное время все время отсылать запрос вебсокету. Вот метод, который выполняется когда сервер присылает сообщение.

```
int onmessage(wsclient *c, wsclient_message *msg) {
  json_object *message;
  message = json_tokener_parse(msg->payload);
  json_object *t, *s;
  json_object_object_get_ex(message, "t", &t);
  json_object_object_get_ex(message, "s", &s);
  fprintf(stderr, "Got new event %s\n", json_object_get_string(t));
  if (strcmp(json_object_get_string(t), "READY") == 0) { // Нужно хендлить именно если заголовок ивента это READY.
      json_object *d = json_object_object_get(message, "d"); // Число, которое нужно отправить на сервер.
      json_object *hb_interval = json_object_object_get(d, "heartbeat_interval"); // Интервал, с которым нужно выполнять запрос.
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Через каждый интервал `hb_interval` мне нужно посылать такую JSON строку, чтобы поддерживать соединение с сервером.

```
{
  "op": 1;
  "d": [тут должно быть число d];
}
```

Как это можно реализовать так, чтобы программа посылала heartbeat запрос и одновременно дальше слушала сервер на запросы?

Я использую [LibWSClient](https://github.com/payden/libwsclient) и [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c).

Comment: В рамках своего обучение недавно столкнулся с той же задачей. Мне посоветовали посмотреть либо многопоточность, либо fork(). fork() показался мне довольно адекватным решением.

Comment: Не знаком с LibWSClient, но если известен сокет, который ее функции используют для обмена с сервером, то лучше посмотрите на [poll](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) (или [select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)). Обе ожидают какого-либо события с заданными файловыми дескрипторами и имеют таймаут. Возможно какой-то аналог этих функций уже  есть и в либе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрел на сорсы LibWSClient. Свое мнение о ее качестве я наверное придержу при себе
(по крайней мере, никакой документации по ссылке я не нашел),
но главным для Вас является то, что чтение и вызов клиентских обработчиков происходят в отдельном потоке.

Т.е. после вызова `libwsclient_run()` Вы сразу продолжаете работу в main (если из ее потока вызывали обработку). Поэтому тут же можно сделать цикл для отправки своих сообщений.

К сожалению всю синхронизацию действий с обработчиками придется делать через глобальные переменные, поскольку либа не предоставляет никакого иного интерфейса.

Т.е. у Вас должно быть что-то такое

```
volatile int done = 0,   // global variables, set on close, error, etc
    can_send_message = 0;
volatile long long msec_hb_interval, // не думаю, что json_object тут это хорошее решение
    message_d;           // число, которое надо отправлять время от времени
// libWSClient event handlers
int onclose(wsclient *c) { 
    done = 1;
    return 0;
}
int onmessage(wsclient *c, wsclient_message *msg) {
   ...
   json_object *d = json_object_object_get(message, "d"); // Число, которое нужно отправить на сервер.
   json_object *hb_interval = json_object_object_get(d, "heartbeat_interval");
   set_globals_from_json(d, hb_interval);
   can_send_message = 1;
   ...
}
....
  int main (int ac, char *av[]) {
    ...
    wsclient *c = libwsclient_new(...);
    ...
    libwsclient_run(c);

    while (!done) {
      if (time_to_send_my_message(msec_hb_interval))
        send_my_message(c, message_d, other_my_data_for_message);
    }

    //blocks until run thread for client is done.
    libwsclient_finish(c);  
    ...
  }
```

А в `time_to_send_my_message()` нужно аккуратно запрограммировать цикл ожидания наступления момента посылки с проверкой переменных `done` и `can_send_message` между засыпаниями, например, на `usleep()`.

Обратите внимание на атрибут `volatile` для глобальных переменных, которые могут изменяться в разных потоках.

Comment: Спасибо, Вы мне подкинули идею как реализовать. Оказывается, что не обязательно присылать heartbeat именно по полученному интервалу. Однако про потоки я не знал, это мне очень помогло!

Comment: Кстати, будьте осторожны с обработкой сигналов при использовании этой библиотеки. Дело в том, что обработчик сигнала может быть вызван в *любом* из потоков программы (если он не замаскирован в нем). Таким образом `recv()` в потоке, который создается в `libwsclient_run()` запросто может быть прерван любым сигналом и вернет -1. Однако, такая ситуация там обрабатывается как ошибка, приводящая к закрытию сокета и прекращению потока. Для надежной обработки сигналов в подобной архитектуре их нужно маскировать (см. `man pthread_sigmask`), однако при создании потока в этой либе никакого хэндлера нет.